# How to know any other inbuilt app opened to hide layout from window manager in android?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am attaching one layout to window manager from my android widget(which floats on all the screens). Now I want to hide that layout from window manager if any app like (browser, settings etc) opened. How to get to know that other app(like browser) got launched ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top App's package name using:

```
Context context = someArbitraryContext;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
    getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

You'll also need the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />` permission.

Once you have the package name, you can use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to figure out which app it is.